# Bluebird promise library: are .map and .filter run in parallel?

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, parallel-processing, bluebird

I'm attempting to write a bunch of async `fs` calls in [bluebird promises](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird). It all works great except that I'm worried about performance. I can't tell if the `.map` and `.filter` functions are executing in parallel or sequentially. Here's my code:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird'),
  fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

module.exports = getDirListing;

function getDirListing(path) {
  function toFullPath(file) {
    return path + file;
  }
  function onlyDirs(file) {
    return fs.statAsync(file).then(function(file) {
      return !file.isFile();
    });
  }
  function ignoreHidden(name) {
    return !(name.substring(0,1) === '.');
  }
  function toModuleNames(dir) {
    return dir.replace(path, '');
  }
  return fs.readdirAsync(path)
    .map(toFullPath)
    .filter(onlyDirs)
    .map(toModuleNames)
    .filter(ignoreHidden);
}
```

I especially care about the call to `onlyDirs` since that is making a bunch of async `fs.stat` calls and can/should be in parallel. I tried looking at [their api docs](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#mapfunction-mapper---promise) but I didn't see anything about parallelization.

Note: I'm not currently in a position to use ECMAScript6 generators (unfortunately).

Also, any other pointers on performance here are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fs.stat calls are done concurrently which you can verify with:

```
var id = 0;
function onlyDirs(file) {
  var d = id++;
  return fs.statAsync(file).then(function(file) {
    console.log("returned from stat call %d", d);
    return !file.isFile();
  });
}
```

```
returned from stat call 0
returned from stat call 1
returned from stat call 2
returned from stat call 3
returned from stat call 5
returned from stat call 4
returned from stat call 6
returned from stat call 7
returned from stat call 8
returned from stat call 10
returned from stat call 11
returned from stat call 14
returned from stat call 13
returned from stat call 9
returned from stat call 15
returned from stat call 18
returned from stat call 17
returned from stat call 16
returned from stat call 12
```

Note the code didn't work originally, I had to modify this:

```
var Path = require("path");
function toFullPath(file) {
    return Path.join(path, file);
}
```